# Pandas: Use first layer of nested dict as columns then the inner dict as rows

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

I'm after creating a table that looks like the below from a 2-layer nested dictionary:

| Day | A | B | C | D | E | F |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| mon | 11,791 | 22,099 | 794 | 52,328 | 337,496 | 3,137 |
| tues | 24,335 | 24,521 | 320 | 50,260 | 264,658 | 3,621 |
| wed | 12,615 | 24,163 | 398 | 42,357 | 413,464 | 3,297 |
| thurs | 13,743 | 27,049 | 1,272 | 40,439 | 325,054 | 4,682 |
| fri | 9,082 | 27,580 | 311 | 38,495 | 343,452 | 7,845 |
| sat | 5,667 | 23,062 | 306 | 40,738 | 282,158 | 13,682 |
| sun | 4,385 | 18,576 | 1,251 | 39,602 | 292,401 | 12,084 |

I've got code that builds a dictionary representing this data that looks like this:

```py
data_collated = {
        "A": {"mon": 11791, "tue": 24335, "wed": 12615, ...},
        "B": {"mon": 22099, "tue": 24521, ...},
        "C": {...},
        "D": {...},
        "E": {...},
        "F": {...},
    }
```

I believe need to throw some sort of dictionary comprehension at this to convert it into tuples? But I'm struggling to wrap my head around it.

*Ideally* a solution will deal with arbitrary numbers of columns (the A-F keys of the outer dict)

My current obviously-wrong attempt at a solution, based on the answer to a related question here, looks like this:

```py
    df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({i: (data_collated[i][j], k)
                                 for j in DAYS.values()
                                 for i in data_collated.keys()
                                 for k in data_collated[i].values()})
```

This produced the A-F columns that I expected, however for obvious reason no "Days" column (which I don't mind too much I can just add that in afterwards, I am exporting to Excel, but not ideal) however it only adds in 2 rows of data after this, not the 7 I would have expected for the 7 days of the week:

|  | A | B | C | D | E | F | G |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 114555 | 213344.4 | 11127.4 | 657818.7 | 3064173 | 46092.46 | 2902111 |
| 1 | 114555 | 213344.4 | 11127.4 | 657818.7 | 3064173 | 46092.46 | 2902111 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're on the right track

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data_collated)
```

Comment: I'm not sure what I've changed, but this didn't work the first time I tried it! I believe the issue may have been because I didn't always have every day mon-sun in each column? No idea but thank you, I was going down a proper rabbit hole.